# Symfony form builder - can I access the fields of the form?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I am using S5. I am at a loss for ideas and don't understand the internals of the form system well enough, to solve my issues.

Inside a controller I have the `$form` object which I can iterate and extract validation errors. However I also need to attach those errors with the ID's of each form field. I can find them well enough in the massive I dump - but getting to that data through chaining is insane and so far not working.

dump()ing the `$form` and navigating that way has resulted in all kinds of crazy chaining and eventual failure (at the proxy):

```
//dump($error->getCause()->getRoot()->getConfig()->getType()->getTypeExtensions());
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be a bit confusing. Do you need it in the template?
https://symfony.com/doc/5.1/form/form_customization.html

```
<label for="{{ form.name.vars.id }}"
    class="{{ form.name.vars.required ? 'required' }}">
    {{ form.name.vars.label }}
</label>
```

You can also find the errors and output them in the template:
https://symfony.com/doc/5.1/form/form_customization.html#form-variables-reference

errors:

> An array of any errors attached to this specific field (e.g.
>   form.title.errors). Note that you can't use form.errors to determine
>   if a form is valid, since this only returns "global" errors: some
>   individual fields may have errors. Instead, use the valid option.

Comment: At the time I was posting the form via Ajax and was trying to return the error bound to the field ID so jquery could show error labels. I’ve since dropped that approach and moved to purely symfony and it works good. I feel like createView() is what was missing in my last approach, seeing as variables are available in twig?